# How to add features to an older version and merge them with the development version in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

At the moment I have only one master branch which represents the current development status of the project. I want to add two features to the release version (which is several commits behind on the master branch), release it, and then merge only the changes from the features into the current development version (master branch). My idea was the following:

1. Check out an older commit from the master branch into a separate release branch.
2. Create a feature branch from the release branch created in 1.
3. Add the features, commit them to the feature branch.
4. Apply only the changes from the feature branch to the development branch.
5. Merge the feature branch with the release branch and delete it.

Assuming that the current release version is 1.5, I would create version 1.6 in the release branch and don’t touch it after adding the features. Only the changes, which would be mainly additional files in form of separate classes, would be merged into the development branch for version 2.0. I want to do it this way, because the code base between 1.5 and 2.0 has radically changed and they’re basically unmergeable at this point.

Is this the correct and easiest way to accomplish my goal? Which specific commands / git functions are necessary to get through all steps? I already thought about using `git flow` for our future development to make use cases like this one easier, but I’m not really sure if it isn’t too complicated and redundant for our simple needs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way should be to use cherry-pick:

1. Check out the release branch
2. Add the features and commit them
3. Check out the master branch and cherry-pick the wanted commits

You can either cherry pick individual commits (i.e. `git cherry-pick <commit>`), or a range of commits (i.e. `git cherry-pick <commit 1>..<commit 2>`)

[git ready - pick out individual commits](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html)

Comment: I’ve read several times that cherry-picking can mess up the repository’s history and produce unnecessary conflicts. What would I have to pay attention to? Is there an easier way to just select all commits from one branch instead of analyzing the log and picking the commit range manually?